# Windows phone Sqlite dosen't return result for a valid query

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have a query that i test against sqlite directly and works fine, but when using it in windows phone 8 app doesn't return a result

```
 string sqlCommandText = "select  a.article_id  article_id, a.book_hierarchy_id  book_hierarchy_id,  b.title  title , b._ID  _ID , b.articles_count  articles_count, b.saved_articles_count  saved_articles_count, b.hierarchy_id  hierarchy_id, b.downloaded_articles_count   downloaded_articles_count " +
                                    "from  hierarchy_articles a inner join book_hierarchy b on b.book_hierarchy_id = a.book_hierarchy_id " +
                                    "where a.book_id = " + bookID + " and a.book_hierarchy_id > " + Consts.HadithKotobsCount + "  order by a.article_id";
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(Consts.DBPath))
            {
                SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
                sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlCommandText;

                List<HadithIndexTemp> babs2 = sqlCommand.ExecuteQuery<HadithIndexTemp>();

            }
```

and here the mapping type

```
public class HadithIndexTemp
    {
        public int article_id { get; set; }
        public int book_hierarchy_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }

        public int _ID { get; set; }
        public int articles_count { get; set; }
        public int saved_articles_count { get; set; }
        public int hierarchy_id { get; set; }
        public int downloaded_articles_count { get; set; }
```

### }

update:
the problem was caused by the "order by" part removed it the it worked fine

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same data set in the Windows Phone app as in your command-line test? How do you get the data to the app?

Comment: yes, copy the database

Comment: And if you copy the string out of the debugger (after it has been constructed with the parameters) and run it against a local SQL database, it works as expected?

Comment: yes---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
using (SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Consts.DBPath))
{
    var result = conn.QueryAsync<HadithIndexTemp>(sqlCommandText).Result;
}
```

Comment: conn.QueryAsync the method dose not exist for the SqliteConnection , i already tried the async one and dosen't work :/

Comment: @HagerAly Can you try SQLiteAsyncConnection because it is working for me,

Comment: the same problem, the query runs fine at the sql editor  but no result is returned to windows phone

Comment: @HagerAly is there any exception ? what is there in result variable ?

Comment: @HagerAly then try a very simple query "Select * From YourTableName" if value is coming in result then there is issue with you query.. not with how you are using sqlite..